# Can't recognize jira-address when using JPT test jira performane

Tags: java, uri, jira, performance-testing

Use JPT to test jira performance

https://github.com/atlassian/jira-performance-tests/blob/master/docs/tests/ON_PREMISE.md

When set jira URI to:

jira-performance-tests/examples/btf-test/src/test/java/com/atlassian/performance/tools/btftest/MyJiraOnPremiseIT.java

```
final URI myJira = new URI("http://192.168.1.1:8080"); // Official example is http://localhost:8090/jira/
jiraOnPremiseTest.setAdminLogin("admin");
jiraOnPremiseTest.setAdminPassword("admin");
```

Under jira-performance-tests/examples/btf-test run:

```
./mvnw verify
```

Got these errors:

```
    at com.atlassian.performance.tools.virtualusers.api.Application.tryRunning(EntryPoint.kt:27)
    ... 29 more

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   MyJiraOnPremiseIT.testMyJira:55 ?  Failed to run with [--jira-address, http://...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.0:verify (default) @ btf-test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.500 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-04T06:39:56Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.0:verify (default) on project btf-test: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/vagrant/jira-performance-tests/examples/btf-test/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My JIRA address is `http://192.168.1.1:8080`. It can been accessed. Why JPT can't recognize it?
This JPT repo hasn't been updated for more than 1 year. Does its source outdated?